# state machine in python

Tags: python, object, state

I am trying to write a state machine whose inputs are the characters of a string (representing a
Python program) and which outputs either (a) the input character if it is part of a
comment or (b) None

but so far I have failed

I got the error TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object

```
def split(word):
    return [char for char in word]

class SM:
    def start(self):
        self.state = self.startState
    def sit(self,inp):
        (s,o) = self.comments(inp,self.state)
        self.state = s
        return o
    def transduce(self,input):
        self.start()
        return [self.sit(inp) for inp in input]

class commentSM(SM):
    startState = ''

    def showcom(self,list,val):
        for char in list:
            if list.find(char) < list.find(val):
                return None 
            else:
                return char

    def comments(self,input,state):
        if state == '':
            return('commented',self.showcom(input,'#'))

input = '''print(hello)  # comment'''
ninput = split(input)

m = commentSM()
print(m.transduce(ninput))
```

Comment: What is the error that you get and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: Also, using builtin names for your variables (e.g. input, list) it likely to lead to confusion and potential errors.

Comment: TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object is the error but I am more concerned about the design of state machine

Comment: `comments()` doesn't return anything when `state != ''`. So you'll get an error when you try to assign that to `(s, o)` on the next iteration.

Comment: When you see any kind of NoneType error, the first thing you should look for is a function that doesn't have a `return` on every path because that's the likely source of the error. I think @Barmar has it right.

Comment: thanks, I correct that mistake but then the outup I get is ['p', 'r', 'i', 'n', 't', '(', 'l', 'o', 'l', 'a', ')', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', 'c', 'o', 'm', 'm', 'e', 'n', 't'. the print does not hide

Comment: `showcom` always returns at the first iteration of the loop, so there is probably something wrong here...

Comment: how can I solve that @ThierryLathuille?